# Wordpress: index.php ничего не выводит

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

К базе данных подключено, никаких ошибок не выводит, но когда захожу на сайт, страница абсолютно пуста. Раньше с такой проблемой еще не сталкивался, на предыдущих сайтах всё работало как нужно. А здесь даже ошибок нет, просто пустая страница. Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Код файла index.php:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<section class="top-info">
        <div class="item slider">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="carousel-2 owl-carousel">
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <?php 

                    $image = get_field('image1');

                    if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>
                        <a href="<?php the_field('link1') ?>">
                        <?php the_field('text1') ?>
                        </a> 
                        </p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <?php 

                    $image = get_field('image2');

                    if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p><a href="<?php the_field('link2') ?>">
                        <?php the_field('text2') ?>
                        </a></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <?php 

                    $image = get_field('image3');

                    if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p><a href="<?php the_field('link3') ?>">
                        <?php the_field('text3') ?>
                        </a> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item ev-calendar">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'calendar' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="item large">
            <?php 
                    $image = get_field('image4');
                    if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <a href="<?php the_field('link4') ?>">
                    <div class="title"><?php the_field('title4') ?></div>
                    <div class="text"><?php the_field('text4') ?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item small">
            <?php 
                    $image = get_field('image5');
                    if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <a href="<?php the_field('link5') ?>">
                    <div class="title"><?php the_field('title5') ?></div>
                    <div class="text"><?php the_field('text5') ?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item subscribe">
            <div class="title"><?php the_field('tr_subscribe', 355) ?></div>
            <div class="wrap">
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="23"]'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="recent-news">
        <div class="base-title"><?php the_field('recent_news', 355) ?></div>
        <div class="carousel-1 owl-carousel">
                <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :  // если имеются записи в блоге.
                    query_posts('cat=3,28,29,30');  // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();  // запускаем цикл обхода материалов блога
                ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="item">
                        <div class="date"><?php the_date('j F Y'); ?></div>
                        <div class="text"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    </a>
                <?php
                    endwhile;  // завершаем цикл.
                endif;
                /* Сбрасываем настройки цикла. Если ниже по коду будет идти еще один цикл, чтобы не было сбоя. */
                wp_reset_query();                
                ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="members">
        <div class="base-title"><?php the_field('our_members', 355) ?></div>
        <div class="members-box">
        
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'mem' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="more-link">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>membership/list-of-member-companiens"><?php the_field('all_members', 355) ?></a>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Код файла htaccess:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag error_reporting E_ALL
php_value display_errors 1
php_value error_reporting 204
```

Comment: А что выводит, если использовать другой шаблон? Или ни один шаблон не работает?

Comment: @labris дело в том, что я даже в wp-admin не могу зайти, везде выводит пустые страницы, куда бы не заходил. Загрузил с сервера это сайт, необходимо правки внести, а он даже не отображается. Если бы я сам его делал, то думаю такой проблемы бы не возникло, а так приходится мучится с трудом других разработчиков. И что самое интересное, на удаленном сервере все отображается, а на локальном не хочет.

Comment: А база данных корректно работает?

Comment: @labris к базе подключается успешно, ошибок не выдает. Изначально думал, что не выдает ошибок потому что и так ничего не выводит, но нет, если поставить некорректные данные подключения к базе, то выдает ошибку подключения к базе, а когда данные корректны, ошибок нет, но и не выводит ничего.

Comment: Самые распространенные причины появления "белого экрана смерти" в WordPress - 1. Ошибка плагина WordPress; 2. Ошибка темы WordPress; 3. Ошибка базы данных.
Третьего вроде у вас нет, значит, скорее всего, виноваты первые две причины. Какие-то настройки не работают на локалхосте (раз сам сайт на удаленному сервере работает нормально). Вы меняли после переноса настройки в таблице wp-options? Где указывается base URL?

Comment: @labris подумал может с темой что-то не так, убрал эту тему из папки тем, по идее должна стандартная использоваться, но все равно белый экран. Когда экспортировал базу данных, то экспортировал в режиме совместимости со старыми версиями mysql, потому что там были такие кодировки как utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci, которые мой mysql сервер не понимал. А по поводу плагинов, то есть подозрение на кокой-то то ли плагин то ли вообще не пойму что. Если заходить на удаленном сервере по адресу http://tnrcoc.nl/wp-admin/ то просит заполнить заявку на вступление вместо стандартного входа, такого еще не встречал.

Comment: Там загадочные редиректы стоят... Вход, по-видимому, через модальное окно, которое открывается при нажатии на пункт меню LOGIN. Я тоже такого раньше не встречал. Какая версия Вордпресс, кстати? А с базой может быть проблема с кодировками. В phpMyadmin нужные поля заполнены (есть контент) или везде пустота?

Comment: @labris Да, вход как раз через то модальное окно, сразу не мог понять как входить, так как редиректило на какую-то заявку. Версия wordpress 4.6.3 Посмотрел в базе wp-options, вроде все норм. Обнаружил, что пустое окно выводит потому, что используется тот index.php который лежит в самом корне вордпресса, а не тот что в корне темы. Подогнал htaccess этого проекта под рабоче проекты и индексные файлы, но безрезультатно. На других проектах отображается index.php в корне темы, а здесь в корне самого wp. Если в корневом файле index.php прописать echo "hello world", то оно как раз выведет эту фразу.

Comment: Чьи-то ручки серьезно поработали, собирая кастомный Вордпресс ): Я бы на вашем месте не стал разбираться, как все теперь там стало хитро устроено, а правил бы то, что нужно поправить, прямо на удаленном сервере, раз там все работает каким-то образом. Можно попробовать сделать бэкап через плагин типа https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/ , но не думаю, что это поможет восстановить сайт на локальном сервере...

Comment: Из комментариев видно, что основной сайт работает, значит, ошибка у вас на локальном. Белый экран смерти - это ошибка php. Сам код скопировать неправильно вы не могли, значит, повреждена база внутри и один из плагинов падает при обработке поврежденных данных. Что вы делали с базой при переносе сайта на локалку? Если глобальная замена имени домена в текстовом дампе - то вот она, причина.

Answer (score 1):

Из комментариев видно, что основной сайт работает, значит, ошибка у вас на локальном. Белый экран смерти - это ошибка php. Сам код скопировать неправильно вы не могли, значит, повреждена база внутри и один из плагинов падает при обработке поврежденных данных. Если изменения в базе произведены глобальной заменой имени домена в текстовом дампе - то вот она, причина. У вас установлен ряд плагинов, которые работают с сериализованнными данными.

Для переноса сайта с сериализованными данными необходимо:

1. Вписать новый домен как в Адрес WordPress (URL), так и в Адрес сайта (URL).
2. Заменить `старый домен` на `новый домен` во всех внутренних ссылках в базе. Это нельзя делать заменой по текстовому дампу базы, поскольку в этом случае сериализованные данные будут повреждены. Лучше всего воспользоваться [DATABASE SEARCH AND REPLACE SCRIPT IN PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: Можно еще такой плагин использовать: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Comment: Еще вариант - взлом и инжект в код

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov какой взлом и инжект? На сайте в инете все ок, проблема на локальном.

Comment: В изначальном вопросе не указано, что сайт на локалке, а инжект это когда в WP инклудится дорген и генерит страницы по нужным ключам.

Comment: Вы комментировали не вопрос, а мой ответ. Не читая.

Comment: Сделал замену этим скриптом, в базе все заменило, а вот экран белый остался. Решил что пока не буду париться с этой проблемой, а правки, которые необходимо внести, буду вносить на удаленном сервере ночью, чтобы клиент не видел, вдруг что поломается:) перед этим просто сделаю бекап и вдруг что, восстановлюсь. А за скрипт спасибо, полезная штука, думаю в будущем обязательно пригодится

Answer (score 0):

> А здесь даже ошибок нет, просто пустая страница. Буду благодарен за
>   любую помощь)

Нужно смотреть логи или/и  включить вывод ошибок на экран.
См [ЧАВО->Белый экран](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD)

Для переноса/клонирования сайта стоит использовать специальные плагины. Напр [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).
Или же после переноса, но не заходя на сайт (это важно!) воспользоваться скриптом [SRDB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).
Ни в коем случае не править базу и дамп в ручную - побьются сериализованные массивы из-за чего будут разные проблемы. Не всегда явные. Могут вылезти и через время (иногда и месяцы) когда уже будет не понятна причина их появления и трудно найти и исправить.